# Unable to parse multiple options in shell properly

Tags: linux, shell

So I need to pass in multiple parameters (Eg: list) to one option and just one parameter to another option and trigger multiple actions based on the input

For Example:

```
./scriptname -a <List of strings> -b one parameter
```

But the whole string is parsed as *-a  -b one_parameter*
throwing errors.

I am using `getopts` method and `-b` is not getting recognized as a separate option.

```
while getopts "a:b:" OPTION
do 

   case $OPTION in 
   a) shift 
        function_a $@
      ;;
   b) shift
        function_b $@
      ;;
   esac 
done
```

so `-a` should accept some commands and trigger `function_a`, and the same applies for `-b`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Meant -b

Comment: I think you need to re-read your shells documentation on `getopts`, in particular what `:` means in the optstring and how an option's argument is handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function prints the arguments passed to it
foo() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
        echo "-> ${1}"
        shift
    done
}

while getopts "a:b:" option
do
   echo "${option}"
   case ${option} in
     a)
        foo ${OPTARG}   # <-- no quotes
      ;;
     b)
        foo "${OPTARG}" # <-- quotes
      ;;
   esac
done
```

Then make sure to quote the list of strings when calling the script:

```
./scriptname -a "foo bar baz" -b "hello world"
a
-> foo
-> bar
-> baz
b
-> hello world
```

Comment: Yeah thank you so much. I did figure the same way out. But since I am new to shell scripting, I am still having a new issue of finding if two flags are called together and take an action based on that

Comment: You could increment a number each time of those flags is passed. If the number equals 2 after the getopts loop, both flags have been passed.

Comment: Thank you. I used a global flag for my case to trigger calls based on getopts